# reading directory inside a csv files using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv

i have a csv file which look like the following

```
/user/desktop/1.jpg, 0
/user/desktop/2.jpg, 0
```

the first column is a file directory and second column is class label

what I want is read the directory one by one, how should i do that?

Now what I try is read the csv file and assign column name and read the column but it seems not working

```
df = pandas.read_csv('csv_file', names=['name','class'])
x = matplotlib.image.imread(df['name'])
```

Comment: Define "not working"

Comment: Your problem is not in CSV or Pandas, but in `matplotlib.image.imread`. The function expects a file name. Instead, you pass a pandas Series.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you shouldn't use pandas like this.
Better is just to open the file and read it row by row, like:

```
import csv    
with open('file.csv', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
         img_path = row[0]
         img_class = row[1]
         matplotlib.image.imread(img_path)
```